# How to replace 1 with first, 2 with second,3 with third etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ordinals

Is there any inbuilt js/jquery function that converts 1 to first, 2 to second, 3 to third... etc.?

ex:

```
Num2Str(1); //returns first;
Num2str(2); //returns second;
```

I dont want to write a function for 100 numbers. Please help.

Comment: umm, show code for starters.., also we do not do your homework

Comment: **No**, there is no inbuilt function.

Comment: The answer is no. but you can write your own function which will be the one of the most useless functions of all time

Comment: @FreshPro i have to be disagree concerning usefulness of this kind of function

Comment: Take a [look at this](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm), I think this could be what your looking for. Although it doesn't use first, second etc. but one, two, three etc.

Comment: @Vogel612 I did not start writing the code yet. I am searching for a built in function to avoid writing it. Looks like there is none available.

Tibos and Vogel612: Thanks for the pointers. They are very helpful!

Comment: I did not know the term ordinals. Hence, couldn't find the relevant thread :( 

Sorry for the duplicate post.

Comment: you can also use Intl.PluralRules read here more https://stackoverflow.com/a/77551647/617373

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no inbuilt function for it.

I did write one for up to 99:

```
var special = ['zeroth','first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth', 'eleventh', 'twelfth', 'thirteenth', 'fourteenth', 'fifteenth', 'sixteenth', 'seventeenth', 'eighteenth', 'nineteenth'];
var deca = ['twent', 'thirt', 'fort', 'fift', 'sixt', 'sevent', 'eight', 'ninet'];

function stringifyNumber(n) {
  if (n < 20) return special[n];
  if (n%10 === 0) return deca[Math.floor(n/10)-2] + 'ieth';
  return deca[Math.floor(n/10)-2] + 'y-' + special[n%10];
}

// TEST LOOP SHOWING RESULTS
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) console.log(stringifyNumber(i));
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/AqetiNOt/1/edit

Comment: This is great.  Thank you.  However, the spelling of "fourtieth" is wrong.  It should be "fortieth"... not to be a spelling nazi or anything.  Just figured I'd point that out.

Comment: @Elliot this looks like a british vs american english thing to me...

Comment: It was useful... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could create a numberbuilder:

You will need to create a foolproof way to convert the single digits by power to a string.

> 1234 -->1(one)*10^3(thousand)+2(two)*10^2(hundred)+3(three)*10(ten)+4(four)*(one)
>       ==> one thousand two hundred th irty four th
>
> 123456 --> one hundred tw enty three thousand four hundred fi fty six th

if you are wondering about the notation: I tried to split this up in the single decision steps you need to make

the rules for building repeat every three digits. The rest is up to you.

Oh and before I forget: there is only "3" exceptions to the th-rule. one, two and three.

Comment: I  guess, you did homework for him. I don't consider you as starter, do you?

Comment: @anand4tech you mean, tibos did the homework and i just showed him how he didn't need to write a switch case for every number possible??

Comment: @anand4tech The answer is useful not necessarily for him, but for others as well.

Comment: @Vogel612: +1 for pointing out the three exceptions!

Comment: Try using the following library: https://github.com/marlun78/number-to-words