# js: fill object with array elements using reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

trying to learn reduce() but can't understand it well yet. Maybe someone from you could help me with my problem.

I have an object with defined keys and an array. I would like to fill up the objects keys with the arrays values using reduce().

My sandbox [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/reduce-assign-array-elements-to-object-keys-e2wv00?file=/src/index.js)

Till now I tried something like this:

```
const myObj = {
  first: null,
  second: null,
  third: null
}

const myArr = [ "abc", "def", "ghi"]

const newObj = myArr.reduce((result, value, index) => {
  result[index] = value
  return result
}, myObj)

console.log(newObj)
// 0: "abc"
// 1: "def"
// 2: "ghi"
// first: null
// second: null
// third: null
```

expected result:

```
{
  first: "abc",
  second: "def",
  third: "ghi"
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: indexes are numbers 0,1,2 and so on.. so it doesnt identify it as first second or third

Comment: @cmgchess thanks, but this I already know. Just dont know, how to change it :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `index` into "an object key at `index`":

```
const newObj = myArr.reduce((result, value, index) => {
    result[Object.keys(myObj)[index]] = value
    return result
}, myObj)
```

That said, `zip` + `Object.fromEntries` would be more appropriate for the job:

```js
const zip = (...args) => args[0].map((_, i) => args.map(a => a[i]));

const myObj = {
    first: null,
    second: null,
    third: null
}

const myArr = [ "abc", "def", "ghi"]

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    zip(
        Object.keys(myObj),
        myArr
    )
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Run through `Object.keys` and reassign the values for each key from `myArr`.

```js
const myObj = {
  first: null,
  second: null,
  third: null
};

const myArr = [ "abc", "def", "ghi"];

Object.keys(myObj).forEach((k,i)=>myObj[k]=myArr[i]);

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) to determine which object `key` to assign value to:

```js
const myArr = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];

const newObj = myArr.reduce((result, value, index) => {
  let key;
  switch (index) {
    case 0: key = "first"; break;
    case 1: key = "second"; break;
    case 2: key = "third"; break;
  }
  result[key] = value;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(newObj);
```

OR, for a more flexible option that does not rely on the descriptive key word:

```js
const myArr = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"];

const newObj = myArr.reduce((result, value, index) => {
  result[(index + 1).toString()] = value;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(newObj);

/*
{
  "1": "abc",
  "2": "def",
  "3": "ghi",
  "4": "jkl",
  "5": "mno"
}
*/
```

---

Here's a SO solution that [converts an integer to an ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20426113/2743458), i.e., 1 to "first", 2 to "second", etc.—up to "ninety-ninth". That gives you ordinal keys, and eliminates the need for the object `myObj`. By depending on `myObj` to provide the key names you'll need to predetermine how many elements are in `myArr`, and be sure there's a key in `myObj` for each.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It just feels like too much typing with all of those switch cases. What if the object has like 100 keys?

Comment: A legitimate concern. What key naming scheme do you propose? First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, etc.

Comment: yes, exacly like this. In the end it really doesnt matter ;-)